# Intervals of Convex and Concave function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function

> Find the intervals where the function is convex and concave.
>   $$f (x) = e^{2x} - 2e^x$$

I tried differentiating twice,  and my answer is: concave when $x < \ln (1/2)$ and convex when $x > \ln (1/2)$. However the key says the other way around...

Comment: did you tried differentiaing twice

Comment: Yes and my answer is: concave when x < ln (1/2) and convex when x > ln (1/2). However the key says the other way around...

Comment: @CasperLindberg Be aware some books assign the names concave and convex in many different ways. What is important is to know what shape the graph has.

Comment: I'm following the book's definition.

Comment: You correctly found the point where the second derivative of the function changes its sign. Now, what you call each half is irrelevant, really. However, if rain falls from above, then $x>\ln1/2$ will collect water because it is concave.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information! The math book's definition is the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f'(x) = 2e^{2x} - 2e^x \to f''(x) = 4e^{2x} - 2e^x$. $f$ is concave if $f''(x) < 0$, and is convex if $f''(x) > 0$. $f''(x) < 0 \iff 2e^x\left(2e^x - 1\right)<0 \iff 2e^x - 1 < 0 \iff e^x < \dfrac{1}{2} \iff x < \ln\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)=-\ln 2$